# Balanced data in cnn image classification

Tags: machine-learning, conv-neural-network

So i have binary classification for image, there are balanced dataset for class a and b.

I have 307 images for each class. i want to ask, when i split to train and test dataset, should the train and test also balanced for each class? or any method to split the dataset

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: i'm working on action classification based on motion hisotry image, so i did preprocess on video dataset and extract them to become MHI then i feed them to my CNN architecture

Comment: How does balancing the train and test set relate to that goal? What problem are you trying to solve by balancing your data?